# Queller's 1985 version of Hamilton's rule

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, mathematical-models, sociality, evolutionary-game-theory

Queller 1985 ("Kinship, reciprocity and synergism in the evolution of social behavior") provides a generalization of Hamilton's rule that allows for non-additivity. To accomplish that, Queller writes the fitness of an individual as
\begin{align}
  W = W_{0} - CP + BP' + DPP'
\end{align}
where $W_0$ is the baseline fitness; $P$ is the phenotypic value (1 for altruist or 0 for nonaltruist); $P'$ is the phenotypic value of the interacting individual; $C$ is fitness cost if $P=1$; $B$ is the fitness
benefit if $P'=1$; $D$ is the deviation from additivity of $C$ and $B$ if
both were altruistic (i.e., $PP' = 1$).

Queller then substitutes this equation into Price's equation $\Delta G = Cov (G, W)$, where $G$ is the frequency of altruism allele in the focal individual($0$, $1/2$ or $1$). The resulting equation is:
\begin{equation}
  - \bar c + \bar b \frac{Cov(G,P')}{Cov(G,P)} + \bar d \frac{ Cov(G,PP') }{Cov(G,P)} > 0
\end{equation}
where $\bar c$, $\bar b$, and $\bar d$ are the sample means of $C$, $B$, and $D$.

**My question is:** how did Queller arrive at the sample means $\bar c$, $\bar b$, and $\bar d$? I understand that $Cov(aX,Y) = a\, Cov(X,Y)$, provided that $a$ is a constant. But what Queller is doing here is different; he seems to be saying that $Cov(AX,Y) = E(A)\, Cov(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just worded a little wierdly in my opinion. The key line in the paper is: 'Fitness components are also defined for all individuals, for example, $C$ is defined, even for a non-altruist, as the cost it would incur if were altruistic.'

Essentially, if it doesn't matter what individual you are you always pay the same cost, then $C$ is a constant. This is pretty much the definition of a constant! The expectation of a constant is just the constant, $E(C) = C$.

The reason it works is that to find whether or not the cost is realised, Queller simply multiplies by the focal individual's phenotype value $P$, which is either 0 or 1. So either the individual pays the cost or it doesn't.

Comment: I think Queller's discussion of his 1985 model in his 1992 paper "Quantitative Genetics, Inclusive Fitness, and Group Selection" (p. 552) is better worded. There he writes the C, B, and D as regression coefficients.